# Cannot access application running inside a docker container

Tags: docker

I'm running a `centos` image in a docker container and in this container, I did run an application on port `3000`. When I access the application on my local machine (`localhost:3000`) I cannot access.
This is the command that I'm using:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v /home/victor/Documentos/doc:/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 centos bash
```

[Application running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW5lv.png)

Answer (score 1):

ensure that the application bind to 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1.

You can check using `docker ps` command

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942153/4087989

Comment: The bind is 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, this is correct, right?

Comment: @VictorMarcantonio your screen capture says the app is open on `localhost:3000` when I think it needs to think it's open on `0.0.0.0:3000`.

Comment: When i open on 0.0.0.0:3000, I cannot access the application.